# Добавление в друзья

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как можно реализовать систему добавления в друзья, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку добавить отправлялся запрос, а у второго пользователя появлялось уведомление "да" или "нет". Как это в базе данных можно сделать красиво без лишних таблиц?

Заранее спасибо. Напишите, пожалуйста, пример добавления и вывода у другого пользователя запроса.

Comment: @raptor96, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: есть форма,таблица user_friend,в ней колонки,user,friends,sd,sd- подтвердил пользователь или нет друга,Вот как ...я хочу узнать как это можно реализовать читая на форумах ничего не нашел особо,дайте хотя бы подсказку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При нажатии на кнопку вызывается js/ajax функция, которая отправляет PHP-скрипту идентификатор пользователя. PHP скрипт добавляет значение в базу и вуаля! Все работает

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, самое просто решение будет следующим:
В таблице `userFriend` должен быть составной ключ по полям `user` и `friend`, по которым Вы будете проводить соответствие пользователя и его друга. А так же колонка `isnew` (если сообщение было отправлено, 1 иначе 0)  По нажатию на кнопку отправляется запрос на сервер с идентификатором друга, сервер создает в бд новую строку с идентификатором пользователя, идентификатором друга и признаком прочитано сообщение или нет. Далее, на клиент добавляется скрипт, который через определенные промежутки времени отправляет на сервер идентификатор пользователя. По полученному идентификатору сервер делает запрос к базе, появились-ли у этого пользователя друзья, запрос типа:

```
select uf.friend from user_friend uf where user = @PARAM and sd = 0 and isnew = 1
```

(если у вас признак нового друга 1) 
и возвращает полученный список новых друзей браузеру. Если список друзей не пуст, браузер выводит уведомление со списком новых друзей. Если пользователь подтверждает друга, браузер отправляет запрос серверу, сервер устанавливает значение sd = 1  в бд для отправленной пары пользователь-друг.